# TypeError: value is undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a controller

```
.controller('ArticlesCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.sum = function(value) { 
    return value.reduce(function(total, article) {
      return total + article.price;
    }, 0); 
  };
});
```

and json

```
[
  {"id": "1", "name": "Pizza Vegetaria", "price": 5 },
  {"id": "2", "name": "Pizza Salami",    "price": 5.5 },
  {"id": "3", "name": "Pizza Thunfisch", "price": 6 },
  {"id": "4", "name": "Pizza Salami",    "price": 5.5 },
  {"id": "5", "name": "Pizza Thunfisch", "price": 6 }
]
```

It works and counts 28 but i get an error in the firebug

```
watch.js (строка 59)
GET http://192.168.1.136:6543/www/an/articles.json
angular.js (строка 10413)
Error: value is undefined
$scope.sum@http://192.168.1.136:6543/www/an/app.js:43:36
anonymous/fn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js line 13036 > Function:2:276
expressionInputWatch@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js:14014:31
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js:15548:34
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js:15824:13
done@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js:10263:36
completeRequest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js:10435:7
requestLoaded@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js:10376:1


return logFn.apply(console, args);
```

Somebody has an idea?

I call the code in the template with `{{ sum(articles) }}`.

Comment: That means scope.articles is undefined at some point.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that since you use

```
{{ sum(articles) }}
```

and load data with AJAX request, at the first cycle of template evaluation `articles` are not yet available. So your `sum` function tries to call `reduce` method of the `undefined`.

The simplest solution is to make `sum` function return `0` if no articles are available:

```
$scope.sum = function(value) {
    return value && value.reduce(function(total, article) {
        return total + article.price;
    }, 0) || 0;
};
```